# Pinned tabs not lighting up when changed in chrome on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, tabs

I just switched to Chrome from Firefox and one of the things I really liked about Firefox was pinned tabs. I found that Chrome has this too, but there are some differences that I don't like.

In Firefox, it doesn't let you navigate away from or close pinned tabs without right clicking on them and selecting "close tab".

I found this feature very useful and convenient. Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't have this and I am unable to find an extension to do this.

I am a programmer so I was considering just making an extension myself. I can live without those features but the most important feature to me was when a page changed, for example Facebook, in Firefox, the tab lit up blue and stayed blue.

For some reason Chrome doesn't do this, all it does is flash a slightly whiter white than tabs normally are. I heard it only does this in the Mac version of Chrome, is there any way to fix this because it makes it very hard to tell when I have a notification on Facebook.

Comment: The behavior is the same on Windows as well.

Comment: Are there any plugins to fix this? It is quite annoying

Comment: If it's by design, then there's no way to fix it because it's not broken. I recommend creating your own plugin, as you suggested.